# How to Get Array Object Values from Controls

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My problem is more than what my Question title says actually. I have a table in which I can enter values per row and add/delete new rows.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="ArrayApp">
    <div ng-controller="arrayController">

          <form ng-submit="addNew()">
                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll" ng-click="checkAll()" /></th>
                                        <th>Item No</th>
                                        <th>Product</th>
                                        <th>Quantity</th>
                                        <th>Unit Price</th>
                                        <th>Line Total</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr ng-repeat="lineItem in lineItems">
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="lineItem.selected"/></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select class="form-control" ng-model="lineItem.item" ng-options="item as item.itemCode for item in items" name="ItemCode" style="width: 100%;">
                                                <option value="0">Select Item</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>

                                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="lineItem.item.itemName"  required /></td>
                                        <td><input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="lineItem.quantity" required /></td>
                                        <td><input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="lineItem.item.unitPrice"  required /></td>
                                        <td><span ng-model="lineItem.lineTotal">{{getLineTotal(lineItem)}}</span></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input ng-hide="!lineItems.length" type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" ng-click="remove()" value="Remove">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary addnew pull-right" value="Add New">
                            </div>
                        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

the script below holds the function to add new rows, delete rows etc.

**Angular**

```
$scope.lineItems = [];
$scope.addNew = function (lineItem) {
                $scope.lineItems.push({
                    'item.itemName': '',
                    'quantity': 1,
                    'item.unitPrice': ''
                });

                //$scope.getTotal();
            };

            $scope.getTotal = function () {
                var total = 0;

                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.lineItems.length; i++) {
                    var lineItem = $scope.lineItems[i];
                    total += (lineItem.quantity * lineItem['item.unitPrice']);
                    vm.salesInvoice.totalAmount = total;
                }

                return total;
            }

            $scope.getLineTotal = function (lineItem) {
                var total = 0;
                if (!lineItem['item.unitPrice'])
                    return total;
                var total = lineItem.quantity * lineItem['item.unitPrice'];
                return total;
            }
```

Now what I am trying to achieve here is this;

I am fetching data from database into vm.items from server and pulling the data into a dropdownlist inside ng-repeat. I want that when I select an item from the dropdown, a corresponding item value will display on the controls of ng-model (lineItem.item.itemName) and lineItem.item.unitPrice inside the table row. This works pretty well with the code displayed here. But the problem here is the displayed values for lineItem.item.itemName and lineItem.item.unitPrice are not captured against their keys in the $scope.lineItems array object. (the values are empty when I debug) To the best of my knowledge I am not seeing anything wrong here. Please I need help.

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LyLt2f7x/) to throw more light on the question. Please help create a sample JSON array for vm.items to see how it works clearly.

Comment: Seems to work fine here. https://jsfiddle.net/LyLt2f7x/2/ I just added a display of the array in the view. Need to be more specific about problem you are having

Comment: @charlietfl Only when a user directly fills the input controls. But I am required to let data based on the `ng-model` be displayed in the corresponding control based on the dropdown selection. I was able to achieve this on my own. But the data displayed does not appear in the `lineItems` data. Maybe you can try using a sample json data for the dropdown that matched the model I specified.